# Java 7 webstart

Tags: java, security, url, java-web-start, jnlp

Legacy Java 5 application now throwing exceptions after moving to Java 7. I have this code in a Java class to return a URL. The URL can either be a filepath or the codebase for the application. 
An error is thrown when the URL is a filepath. What is  going wrong here?
It worked perfectly in Java 5.

Comment: "_An error is thrown_" Which error? And is it an error or exception?(You used both terms in your post)

Comment: It throws a file not found exception when the URL is trying to locate the filepath.                                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://urlforwebstartapp/filename
 ....                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22765459/edit) your question and add the whole stacktrace. It may help in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a long (long) time Sun had been saying *"Don't put application resources in the application installation directory!".*

They decided to make that advice a little more formalized some time during 1.6 (AFAIR) by ensuring that *no applet or app. deployed using JWS could get the installation path even if it already had declared **all permissions***!  For apps. that tried, the JVM will 'lie' and point directly back to the place from which the Jars were first downloaded, even if they were cached locally and the JVM was using the files from the cache.

So, (according to that decision) the app. is broken and needs fixing.  If you raised a bug report, it would be closed as 'not a bug'.

On a side note:

```
URL fileurl = new URL(getCode() + file);
```

Should probably be:

```
URL fileurl = new URL(getCode(), file);
```